# Multitasking, how to run more than one object in foreach in the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, operating-system

I have more than one reader and I want to run all at the same time. I get reader IP and data from the same query in database use this query:

```
var deviceSetupsInfo = entities.LaneDeviceSetups
                  .Where(e => e.DeviceTypeId == 1)
                  .Select(e => new {
                     e.Ip,
                     e.LaneId,
                     e.TableName,
                     e.DeviceTypeId
                 }).ToList();
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < deviceSetupsInfo.Count; i++) {     
         Task.Run(() => new RFIDReader(
                            deviceSetupsInfo[i].Ip, 
                            deviceSetupsInfo[i].LaneId.Value,
                            deviceSetupsInfo[i].TableName, 
                            deviceSetupsInfo[i].DeviceTypeId.Value
                        )
         );
}
```

I want all return readers in `[i]` in loop run in the same time.

Comment: what is RFIDReader

Comment: why not `Forech(var item in deviceSetupsInfo) {  }`, you need to include what RFIDReader actaully is, more code needed

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach`. Or `AsParallel().Select()`. I mean it is likely going to be massively slower...

Comment: Your code may be affected by this problem: [Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

parallel.foreach is the solution, lock is optional to avoid the edge cases

```
 object locker = new object();
    Parallel.ForEach(deviceSetupsInfo, (item) =>
                 {
                       //do stuff
                     
                 });
```

Comment: The `lock` statement creates synchronized blocks of code, where only one thread can enter at a time. As such, it defeats the purpose of `Parallel.ForEach` IMHO.

Comment: If parallell processes are sharing same object due to any reason, it would break without a lock. Lock necer makes in synchrounous. It holds resources just for a fraction

Comment: thank you i use it 
 ` new Thread(() => Parallel.ForEach(deviceSetupsInfo,
                    device =>                  )).Start();`